# Does The Guardian of Forever have any defensive capabilities?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The Guardian of Forever appears to be a large sentient time portal. It is apparently both being and machine. Does it have any defensive capabilities? I don't know its durability, but it seems awfully vulnerable, considering it probably can't move on its own. Imagine if a horde of Nausicaans and Chalnoth invades the planet with high-energy weapons, or if a Borg Cube decides to bombard the planet from orbit, etc.

Comment: No match for an angry Harlan Ellison.

Comment: It has the power to control time and space. I suspect an attack would rapidly find itself having never existed.

Comment: Wasn't it destroyed though in the mirror universe during tos times @valorum (in the only tos mirror universe one)

Comment: @Thomas - write that up as an answer :-)

Comment: @valroum I'm going by memory there and it is about 20 years that I saw that episode so I wasn't sure

Comment: It has the power to defy the laws of physics for the entire universe. I doubt a Borg ship could prevail against it.

Comment: are you asking about protection from destruction or protection from misuse? If the later, then in the novel "Federation" (which events of later films have *possibly* overridden but is nonetheless a good book) - the Guardian is shown as capable of 'shutting down' at will and being completely useless (but then re-enabling)

Comment: Destruction. Perhaps the mortal races couldn't affect the Guardian, but I find it hard to believe that Q (who claims to be able to control all matter, space, and time) couldn't do so. You could even argue that some of the time-manipulators could at least affect the Guardian to some degree (Krenim, Prophets, etc.). I'm not saying that the latter could certainly destroy the Guardian. Ultimately, we don't know all that much about the rock. Possibly it's particularly vulnerable to living energy, and so a species as "weak" as the Calamarain could kill it. There's no way to know absolutely.

Answer (score 5):

First off, the Guardian of Forever claims to be *five billion years old*. That's half-a-billion years older than Earth (TNG: *All Good Things*, *The Chase*, and current scientific dating). If we accept its statement, it would need to be super, exceedingly strong to survive wind, rain, and dust weathering!

The Guardian also claims to be "its own beginning and its own ending." Again, if we accept it at its word, it almost sounds like one of Doctor Who's "fixed points in history"; because it exists through all of history, nothing you do to it can really destroy it. Its planet is surrounded by "ripples in time," so it's entirely possible that the rules of entropy don't actually apply to the Guardian itself.

It's never stated what the Guardian is made of, but Star Trek does contain its own nigh-indestructible material:  neutronium. The Doomsday Machine was made out of it, and no weapons could penetrate its hull. It's possible that the Guardian was made of neutronium.

The Guardian has another non-obvious defense: silence. In *Federation,* by Judith and Garfield Reeves-Stevens, the Guardian is being studied by the Federation, but it refuses to speak.  Except for the temporal waves that emit from it, it could just be any other inert rock on the planet.  Anyone to whom it doesn't want to interact, it can always decide to be silent.

Finally, in the *Q Continuum* series of books, a young Q attempts to pull 0 (pronounced "null"), a similarly omnipotent being from another reality altogether, through the Guardian. The Guardian refused to let 0 through, because it recognized that he didn't belong on our plane. The Guardian put up a kind of "border" or "skin" over the portal, and 0 was unable to force his way through. Q, being Q, called the Guardian a "pompous piece of rock" and pulled 0 through the barrier (with a loud snap and a ton of special effects).  Think about it: the Guardian was able to keep an **omnipotent being** from stepping through, and it took **two omnipotent beings** combining their wills to finally, barely, succeed. I'd hate to be at the receiving end of that kind of defensive power.

Comment: Does Neigh indestructible material just work against horse noises?

Comment: How can you have 'two' omnipotent beings?

Comment: Well, that's not canon, of course. I personally think Q could destroy the Guardian with a thought if he desired.

Comment: The Q continuum is made up of multiple omnipotent beings, @Valorum.  According to canon, it just turns into a hissy fit of countermanding reality if the beings are opposing each other.  Also, we only have Q's word that he's actually, really, omnipotent.  He appears omnipotent to us, so we call him omnipotent, but there's always the possibility that the Q are only mostlypotent.

Comment: It is canon that the Guardian claims to be it's own beginning and end, @T-1000'sSon.  If we take it at it's word, it would seem to me that Q might be able to modify it, or move it, or bore it to death, but even Q can't DESTROY it. Q claims his species have taken on the job of maintaining the universe's integrity (I know it's said so in novels, I'm pretty sure he's hinted to it in Canon), so destroying a fixed point of time sounds dangerous to me.

Comment: For posterity, @Peter 's comment refers to my 2AM typo for nigh-indestructible.

Comment: @Zoey Boles I am totally stealing the word "mostylpotent". Edit: also stealing "mostlypotent"

Comment: Enjoy it with my blessing, @Irishpanda!

Comment: Q is pretty powerful. We've seen him alter time with a snap of his fingers. Why should it be so hard that he couldn't destroy a time-monitoring sentient being?

Comment: I'm saying The Guardian isn't part of the system in which it monitors. Something being it's own cause is theology level stuff. My supposition is that the Guardian is "out of bounds" for Q.  He can do whatever he wants within our universe, but the lopsided donut we see on the show is only the Guardian's "presence" in our (3,4,7,12,whatever)-dimensional world. It's also possible that Q *can* destroy the Guardian, but *wouldn't dare try* because the consequences to the universe may be grave if it's as powerful and intertwined with time as it claims. (to @T-1000'sSon)